# How can I check if my variable exists in an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I am working on a project where I want to check if my variable exists in an object and I want to return the location where it exists.

Here is an example of my object (called data):

```
[
0: {ArticleNumber: "ART0001", Name: "Ticket1", Branche: "Railway1"}
1: {ArticleNumber: "ART0002", Name: "Ticket2", Branche: "Railway2"}
]
```

Now I have a variable that is:

```
var articleNumber = "ART0001"
```

What I now want to do is to check if my variable articleNumber is in my object and then I want to return the number (in this case 0).

Have tried the following code:

```
var arrayNumber = Object.values(data)
var number = arrayNumber.indexOf("ART0001")
```

Unfortunately number now returns a -1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 data.findIndex((ele) => ele.ArticleNumber == "ART0001")
```